# Does it make sense to optimize the table after alter table drop column?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I dropped the column `name` in table `employees`. 
If I run `OPTIMIZE TABLE employees`, will it reduce space usage?

My thoughts:

The documentation says that `optimize table` is equal to `alter table` for InnoDB (if I read this   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html#optimize-table-innodb-details correctly).

Also, `alter table drop column` changes rows structure in the table, so it should rewrite all rows. This is where, I assume, optimization happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to OPTIMIZE TABLE on an InnoDB table after running any ALTER TABLE that changes the row size.

The ALTER TABLE copies rows into a new tablespace, and rebuilds indexes. This will accomplish the same defragmentation you hoped to do with OPTIMIZE TABLE.